# to improve performance on query

Tags: mysql, performance

I hava nest query:

```
SELECT PIXEL_X as 'X_Coord', PIXEL_Y as 'Y_Coord', 
CONVERTWATTS2DBM_udf(SUM(L2_VALUE)/SUM(L3_VALUE)) as 'Pixel_Value' 
   FROM table  
   WHERE  
      ('GSM 850/900' like CONCAT('%',FILTER2,'/%') OR 
       'GSM 850/900' like CONCAT('%/',FILTER2,'%') ) 
GROUP BY X_Coord, Y_Coord;
```

but takes a long time, could you help me to improve their performance?

Thanks

Comment: Querying relational databases with %..% filtering is inefficient - it almost always requires table scans. What type of engine are you using for your tables: MyISAM or InnoDB? Have you tried running this query with no grouping to check how much time does the filtering takes? Finally what are possible values for FILTER2 and what values are in the 'GSM 850/900' column?

Answer (score 0):

A straight forward method to optimize would be this:

- Create the filter variable yourself, in whatever language you use to access the database.
- Set one query for each option for "GMS 850/900", then join them together using UNION, like so:

  ```
  SELECT PIXEL_X as 'X_Coord', PIXEL_Y as 'Y_Coord', 
  CONVERTWATTS2DBM_udf(SUM(L2_VALUE)/SUM(L3_VALUE)) as 'Pixel_Value' 
  FROM table  WHERE  
  'GSM 850/900' like '%YOURVALUE1%'
  UNION
  SELECT PIXEL_X as 'X_Coord', PIXEL_Y as 'Y_Coord', 
  CONVERTWATTS2DBM_udf(SUM(L2_VALUE)/SUM(L3_VALUE)) as 'Pixel_Value' 
  FROM table  WHERE  
  'GSM 850/900' like '%YOURVALUE2%'
  ```

This should speed up the query.

Furthermore, it would speed up the query alot if you generated the values you generate on the fly beforehand. You could create a column and generate the CONVERTWATTS2DBM_udf in a ON WRITE trigger. This would remove the necessity of running this function not only on every row, but also on every run of the query itself.

Lastly, a composite index over Pixel_X, Pixel_Y and your newly created column could speed up the query further.

Comment: thanks for your answer but not improve and the table is temporal, Is it possible to create index in temp tables?

Comment: Of course. A temporary table is, for all accounts and purposes, equal to a normal table. Only the scope is different. Temporary tables can be scoped to a connection, meaning that a close of the connection disposes of the temporary tables scoped to it.